# Hybris Error - no tenant active. if you do not want to use tenants, call Registry.activateMasterTenant() to assure the Master tenant is active

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am migrating Hybris version 6.2 to 6.5 getting this error

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: no tenant active. if you do not want to use tenants, call Registry.activateMasterTenant() to assure the Master tenant is active.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.298 |     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getCurrentTenant(Registry.java:821)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.298 |     at de.hybris.platform.util.Config.getParameter(Config.java:223)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.298 |     at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.util.impl.PlatformSystemPropertyResolver.getProperty(PlatformSystemPropertyResolver.java:61)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.298 |     at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.CockpitUIFactory.getPageDefinitionExternal(CockpitUIFactory.java:73)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.298 |     at com.hybris.cockpitng.util.CockpitUIFactory.getPageDefinition(CockpitUIFactory.java:63)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.298 |     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:205)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.298 |     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:137)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:140)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.299 |     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.300 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.300 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.300 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.300 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.300 |     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.300 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.300 |     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.300 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.301 |     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.301 |     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.301 |     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.301 |     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.301 |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.301 |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.301 |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.301 |     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.301 |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/11/25 12:26:19.302 |
```

I am assuming this would cause Filter - Filter is not working correctly or not setting tenant.

Can anyone pls help out....

Comment: Is it an error during startup?

Comment: No, it is at the time when saying https://localhost:9002/backoffice/